# Cross browser - CSS padding issues

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I am trying to make a validation box after an input field, however, across different browsers the sizing goes wrong e.g. there is a big difference between firefox and chrome.

Is there a better way to make this box so that the sizing is equal across all browsers? Here is the code and a jsfiddle of how I am doing it at the moment : http://jsfiddle.net/wPS7t/

And here is an image of the problem:

[image]

### HTML

```
    <form id="formStyles">

        <div id="inputWrapper">
            <input type="text"/>
            <label id="xlabel">x</label>
        </div>                         

    </form>
```

### CSS

```
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            font-family: Calibri;
        }

        *, *:before, *:after {
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #formStyles{
            width: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            top: 200px;
            position: relative;
        }

        input{
            font-size: 18px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #inputWrapper{
            position: relative;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            width:400px;
        }

        #xlabel{
            background-color: red;
            padding: 7.2px;
            color: white;
            left: -6px;
            position: relative;
            top:-1px;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try padding 7px? I'm not positive but I don't think both browsers except 7.2px as a result and probably is rounding it.

Comment: Nope sorry, didn't change anything